# Get values of dynamically created row via PHP/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I needed to get the values of each dynamically created rows and print those values. What the current code does is that it can alert the all the added values or print to console. Now, how can I print those values?

For instance user has added one more row and selected the following:

[image]

After the user clicks Get Values, all the values (Female, Lady, Male and Schertz) must be printed to a generated table and page should look like this:

[image]

Now what I have are the following code.

HTML view:

```
<button>Add More Order</button>
<button>Delete Added Order</button>

<div id="wrap" class="order-container">
  <p>       
    <select class="getThis">
      <option>--Gender--</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>   
    <input type="text" class="getThis" placeholder="Name"/>
  <br>
  </p>
</div>

  <input type="submit" id="getValues" value="Get Values"></input>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Add new row   
    $("button:nth-of-type(1)").click(function(){
        $("#wrap").append("<p><select class='getThis'><option>--Gender--</option><option>Male</option><option>Female</option></select><input type='text' class='getThis' placeholder='Name'/><br></p>").trigger('create');
    });

    //Remove last added row
    $("button:nth-of-type(2)").click(function(){
        $("p:last-of-type").remove();
    });

//alert values
$("#getValues").click(function() {
        $(".getThis").each(function() {
           var getThis =  $(this).val();
           //console.log(getThis);
           alert(getThis);

     });

  });

}); // Document Ready End
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPBa3/2/) for a demo.

Any ideas? Kamsahamnida!

Comment: `How can I put the values into input type=text` Which input???

Comment: can you plz explain in which textbox you want value.

Comment: My apologies, @A.Wolff, I was not able to clear which input I'm referring to. I edited my question. Anyway, I'm planning to get all the values the user has entered (the name and gender) and put those values to an <input type="text">.

Comment: Please, consider to explain expected behaviour providing relevant sample. You want ONLY dynamic elements? What if more than one dynamic element, must create more input text or fill already existing ones? So then, should e.g names separated by comma or what? Etc... Still unclear what you are asking

Comment: @A.Wolff, I updated my post. Was I able to clear my question? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use e.g:

### DEMO

```
$("#getValues").click(function () {
        var $table = $('#resultTable').length ? $('#resultTable').find('tr:gt(0)').remove().end() : $('<table/>').append('<tr><th>Gender</th><th>Name</th>').appendTo('body').attr('id', 'resultTable');
        var getValues = $("p:has(select.getThis)").find('select.getThis').map(function () {
            return {
                gender: this.value,
                name: $(this).next().val()
            }
        }).get();
        $.each(getValues, function (_, fields) {
            $table.append($('<tr/>', {
                html: '<td>' + fields.gender + '</td><td>' + fields.name + '</td>'
            }))
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $("#getValues").click(function() {
    $("select.getThis").each(function() {
       var getThis =  $(this).val();
       $(this).next().val(getThis);
 });});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jPBa3/1/)**

Comment: +1 I understand question like this too even doesn't make much sense

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Milind Anantwar. Something like that. But I'll try to work on your code. Btw, I updated my post. :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
document.getElementById('getValues').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your inputs class to something else as it might start confilcting and then try this:

```
$("#getValues").click(function() {
  $(".getThis").each(function() {
    var getThis =  $(this).val();
    $(this).closest("p").find("input[type='text']").val(getThis);
  });
});
```

What it does is it goes from the current target to the closest parent paragraph tag and from there it finds the input[type='text'] and gives it the value

Comment: Hi, @Karl Viiburg. I appreciate your answer. I have changed my question above. :)